# Do views from YouTube iframe player embed in iOS app count on Youtube?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

if i embed YouTube iframe player (using youtube api) into my iOS app, will the views from my app count on youtube?

Answer (score 1):

If you auto-play the video it won't count but you can have it count as long as you don't auto-play and let the user interacts with a 'Play' button.
YouTube counts every view which has crossed minimum 30 seconds as written in one of the [blog](https://marketingland.com/whats-a-video-view-on-facebook-only-3-seconds-vs-30-at-youtube-128311) of video no matters where it is from.

**Note:** majority of posts and blogs says that it count of minimum 4 to 5 sec view but some says it of minimum 30 seconds.